# pass javascript object in html in onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

i am working on  accordian with static data , but i don't know how to pass javascript object and function in  and also i want to change Accordion content on change event content

Code:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.categories a{
    color: #414141;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 3px 0px;
  }

  .nav-item a .active{
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  .nav-item a:hover {
    color: #3384f7;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
 
  .card{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
 .card-header a{
    color: #414141;
  }
  .card-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .card-header a:hover {
    color: #3384f7;
  }

    .live-lable {
                color: white;
                border-radius: 14px;
                padding: 0px 9px;
                line-height: 1.7;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-decoration: underline;
                cursor: pointer;
                color: rgb(125, 125, 125);
                border: 2px solid rgb(125, 125, 125);
                margin-right: 15px;
            }

</style>
<script>
   var ListArray =[ 
  {
    id:1,
    name:'Stack Export',
    description:'Export your complete stack back in an excel sheet ',
    category:'Data Recovery',
    status:true,
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:'Microsoft Excel Importer',
    description:'Import an excel file to create a new stack or import it to a table. ',
    category:'Import',
    status:true,
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name:'Append CSV file in an existing table',
    description:'Import a CSV file into an existing table and map the columns to take the form of your table. ',
    category:'Data Transformation',
    status:true,
  },
]
var CategoryList =[
  'Data Recovery',
  'Import',
  'Data Transformation',
]
function handleChangeCategory(category){
  
      let activeCategory = 'All';List = ListArray, categoryList=CategoryList;
      if(category =="All"){
            List=ListArray,
            activeCategory="All"
      }else{
          let data = ListArray.filter((e)=>e.category == category)
              List=data;
              activeCategory=category;
              categoryList.map((category)=>{
              return(
                <li className={activeCategory === category ? "active-category" : ''} onClick="handleChangeCategory(category)"> 
                  {categoryList.category}
                  </li>
                    )
                  })
      }
    }
handleChangeCategory('All');

</script>
<section class="my-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 categories">
            
            <h2 class="mt-3" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 20px;">categories</h2>
             <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item" onclick="">
                <a style="text-decoration: underline;" class="nav-link active" href="onClick='handleChangeCategory('All')'">All</a>
              </li>

            </ul> 
          </div>
     
        <div class="col-md-9" id="root">
          <div role="tablist" id="accordion-1">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" role="tab">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-1 .item-1" href="div#accordion-1 .item-1">Stack Export</a>
                <a class="live-lable" style="color: white;background: #4FAD35; border: 2px solid #4FAD35;margin-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 1px;">Live </a> 
              </div>
              <div class="collapse show item-1" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#accordion-1">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">Export your complete stack back in an excel sheet .</p>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
       
      </div>
           
       
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

i am creating a static array **ListArray and  CategoryList** for mapping purpose , when i click on **CategoryList**  then it will show data of **ListArray** of mapping **category** and created a function
**function handleChangeCategory(category)** and how to used in html code

any one help out please

thanks!

Comment: (offtopic - but since often mistyped) It's *accordion* not *accordian*.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i will used from bootstrap-accordion

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan can u run the code and change my code according requirement

Comment: Can you explain what's going on with return statement of handleChangeCategory function? It looks like you;re returning a DOM, I doubt that is supported..

Comment: @Jry9972   return statement will map with category list with listarray data